# Remove conditional sequence from string in R

Tags: r, string

I have a sequence encoded in a string, but one type of step in this sequence is entirely conditional on a previous step.

When this occurs, I'd like to remove the previous step.

For example, in the case:

> "alpha_i, bravo_i, alpha_i, alpha_c, charlie_i, bravo_i, bravo_c,
>   alpha_i, delta_c"

those steps where a *_c event occurs directly after an *_i event, I'd like to have the *_i event removed, the desired result being:

> "alpha_i, bravo_i, **alpha_c**, charlie_i, **bravo_c**, alphai_i,
>   delta_c"

In other words,

> "alpha_i, alpha_c" goes to just "alpha_c"
>
> "bravo_i, bravo_c" goes to just "bravo_c",

but we do not change "alpha_i, delta_c" because they are a different event name.

I think the syntax would use the gsub function, but I don't know how to match the prefixed term either side of the comma, and would appreciate some help.

*In addition to the point raised below; yes there will be many different examples of event names, not just the two being replaced here.

Comment: Is this specific to the two cases you mention or can the be many more alpha/bravo like values for which you need to do the replacement? (If not, you can just use two gsub calls)

Comment: Thank you, good point. I will edit my original question to include this information. In practice, yes there will be many different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wds <- c("alpha_i", "bravo_i", "alpha_i", "alpha_c", "charlie_i", "bravo_i", "bravo_c", "alpha_i", "delta_c")

wds[cumsum(rle(as.character(substr(wds, 1, gregexpr('_', wds))))$lengths)]
```

Alternatively, if your vector is of length 1, try this:

```
wds <- c("alpha_i, bravo_i, alpha_i, alpha_c, charlie_i, bravo_i, bravo_c, alpha_i, delta_c")
wds_split <- unlist(strsplit(wds, ', '))
wds_split[cumsum(rle(as.character(substr(wds_split, 1, gregexpr('_', wds_split))))$lengths)]
```

Comment: OP seems to start from a character vector of length 1

Comment: You're right. I've now added a possible solution for that as well.

Comment: Very clever! Then `paste(wds_split, collapse = ', ')` to reform the string. Thank you

Comment: @Jon, this approach doesn't look at the endings (c or i) - wasn't that part of the question?

Comment: Yes - it does. Was trying to edit (too late).  I lose instances where two *_i , *_i follow one another, and explicitly it has to be event_i , event_c